# Kirchhoff's Current & Voltage Laws

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, inductor, kirchhoffs-laws

What are Kirchnoff's current and voltage laws? I've tried doing some research but most explanations are quite complex.

Also how can I solve the attached question using these laws??

[image]

Comment: KVL and KCL are very essentially laws that utilize Ohm's Law to tell us how to set up equations at particular areas of a circuit. KVL tells us (according to Wikipedia) that "the algebraic sum of the products of the resistances of the conductors and the currents in them in a closed loop is equal to the total emf available in that loop." KCL tells us "The algebraic sum of currents in a network of conductors meeting at a point is zero."

Comment: (continued) Therefore, in order to solve for \$v_o\$, you can perform mesh current analysis, node voltage analysis, placing it in the Laplace domain, etc. The equations are something that you have to figure out. I've never heard of MNA... Can you tell me what that stands for? (edit: I'm assuming it means "mesh network analysis?")

Comment: I hate to say it... but if you don't know KCL and KVL, you certainly aren't ready to attempt the problem you provided. First things first. (And simpler circuits before more complex ones.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this puts the two laws in somewhat simpler forms for you;

Kirchoff's Current Law states (as you have probably seen) that the sum of currents entering a node is equal to the sum of currents leaving it. Think of a junction of water pipes where three pipes meet at a T-shaped junction. The flow of water into the junction must be equal to the flow of water out, otherwise water would be appearing out of nowhere. Similarly, in an electric circuit the flow of charge into the junction must be equal to the flow of water out, otherwise charge would be appearing out of nowhere.

Kirchoff's Voltage Law is probably the trickier one to understand. Basically it says that if you start at a node in a circuit and you follow some closed loop around the circuit back to the same node you have to be at the same voltage you started at. A mathematician would say this is because the electrostatic field is conservative. In more understandable terms, it is because voltage is a potential difference i.e. the difference in potential energy a charge would have if you moved it from one point to the other. A good analogy here is gravity, a mass has gravitational potential energy proportional to its height above some reference, say sea level. To change the potential energy you move the mass up or down, it doesn't matter what path you take between your two end points. I might move a mass 100m up then l00m to my left and then 100 m back down to the height I started at, the mass has the same gravitational potential energy I started with because it is at the same height even though it is in a different position. Relating back to electric circuits, if I move around a loop in a circuit, I end up back at the same 'height' with the same voltage.

Comment: Thanks! How would you go about solving the attached question?

Comment: For a start writing KCL equations at each node would be a decent idea. Look up Nodal analysis to go from there.